# what is the directory user_upload in TYPO3 6.1 installs for?

Tags: typo3

What is the directory "user_upload" in TYPO3 6.x installations (inside the auto-created fileadmin) - and can it be safely deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fileadmin/user_upload/ is the basic default upload folder for all editors for RTE images, for uploading in the Element Browser without choosing a directory. Fixed since TYPO3 6.0.5.

The default upload folder for the RTE is defined by the userTSconfig of each user:

options.defaultUploadFolder = 1:/mypics/

source: http://wiki.typo3.org/File_Abstraction_Layer#What_do_the_different_folders_mean.3F

Comment: So if RTE image upload is disabled anyway, can it be deleted? Or... what about "direct upload" (the upload button right in the content element)? I haven't seen it in 6.x, has it been removed?

Comment: Direct upload still exists. When you click "Add image" on an image content element, you see it under the folder tree. The default folder is the same as for RTE uploads and can also be changed with the typoscript I posted. So you can delete it, but you probabely should provide a different folder, because you will get an error when opening "Add image" with a non existing default upload folder.